# Setting text color of the Windows console is not working as expected

Tags: winapi, colors, console, rust, kernel32

I am trying to change the Windows console foreground text color with Rust using the winapi and kernel32 crates.

```
[dependencies]
winapi = "0.2.8"
kernel32-sys = "0.2.1"
```

**Code**

Enum where I store the foreground color values:

```
#[repr(u16)]
pub enum ForegroundColor {
    RED =  (winapi::FOREGROUND_INTENSITY | winapi::FOREGROUND_RED) as u16,
    CYAN = (winapi::FOREGROUND_INTENSITY | winapi::FOREGROUND_GREEN | winapi::FOREGROUND_BLUE) as u16,
    // ...
}
```

Function that gets the output handle:

```
use winapi;
use winapi::{CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO, COORD, HANDLE, SMALL_RECT, WORD};
use kernel32;

static mut CONSOLE_OUTPUT_HANDLE: Option<HANDLE> = None;
pub fn get_output_handle() -> HANDLE {
    unsafe {
        if let Some(handle) = CONSOLE_OUTPUT_HANDLE {
            handle_check(handle);
            handle
        } else {
            let handle = kernel32::GetStdHandle(winapi::STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
            handle_check(handle);
            CONSOLE_OUTPUT_HANDLE = Some(handle);
            handle
        }
    }
}

fn handle_check(handle: HANDLE) {
    if handle == winapi::INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE {
        panic!("NoConsole")
    }
}
```

Function that sets the foreground color
     use kernel32;

```
// ForegroundColor is a struct containing win32 colors
pub fn set_foreground_color(for_color: ForegroundColor) {
    // function shown above
    let output_handle = kernel::get_output_handle();
    // cast the enum value to a u16: fn to_u16(&self) -> u16 { *self as u16 }
    let forground_color = for_color.to_u16();

    unsafe {
        kernel32::SetConsoleTextAttribute(output_handle, forground_color);
    }
}
```

In my `main.rs`  I am creating a box that is 20 blocks on X and 20 on Y. I want to give the border a color of `CYAN` and the inside a `RED` color.

```
// for example 1 has to be cyan and 2 red but than on larger scale
// 1111
// 1221
// 1111
for y in 0..21 {
    for x in 0..21 {
        if (x == 0 || y == 0) || (x == 20 || y == 20) {
            // function shown above
            set_foreground_color(ForegroundColor::CYAN);
            // Print a cyan colored ■
            print!("■")
        } else {
            // function shown above
            set_foreground_color(ForegroundColor::RED);
            // Print a red colored ■
            print!("■")
        }
    }
    // reset cursor to start of new line
    println!();
}
```

For some reason, all `■` will have the `CYAN` color and there will not be any red ones.

When I have the same code and replace the `print!()` with `println!()`, it will print both the `RED` and `CYAN` colored blocks as expected. All the `■` have the right color as expected but the problem now is that the `■` are on their own row.

Why is the color of the text changing as expected when using `println!()`? Why can I not have different colors on the same line with  `print!()`? Is there some buffer in winapi that stores the color of the console lines? Do I need to specify it somewhere before I can use multiple colors in one line?

Comment: The Windows console is notoriously tricky with non-ASCII values; try with something simpler than ■?

Comment: @Shepmaster `■` is placed in the ASCII table if you press `<ALT> + 254` you get this block. And this problem occurs also with normal numbers (just tried out).

Comment: I would strongly recommend that you go back and reread what ASCII is. Only the numeric values less than 128 are ASCII.

Comment: @Shepmaster Okay, but if I use `1` or `2` instead of the `■` these numbers will still have the same color: `CYAN` instead of `1` being cyan and `2` being red. So that could not be the problem though?

Comment: Yes it does seem unlikely to be a non-ASCII issue in that case.

Comment: You need to check whether `SetConsoleTextAttribute` is successful. It return `FALSE` if it fails. If setting the default text attribute succeeds, and it's still not working, then maybe Rust `print` calls low-level `WriteConsoleOutput` with a default text attribute or `WriteConsoleOutputCharacter`, which doesn't modify the existing text attribute.

Comment: Try implementing your own print function that calls `WriteConsoleW` with a UTF-16 wide-character string. This will also solve any codepage problems. However, the console doesn't use Uniscribe or DirectWrite to handle characters beyond the BMP, complex scripts, and fallback fonts.  Codes beyond the BMP will be displayed as two default glyphs for the UTF-16 surrogate pair. For codes in the BMP, displaying the character requires direct support in the current font.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rust's standard output is line-buffered. So your text gets sent to the console one line at a time, meaning the entire line will have the same color.

You can flush the output after each `print!` using:

```
use std::io::Write;

std::io::stdout().flush().expect("Flush stdout failed");
```

Comment: Works Perfect!! That explains a lot.